# Scan and generate a map (for use with thrust::scatter)

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'd like to use thrust to create an array which contains the all the indices that pass a test. I think I'm missing something here, as I can't seem to work out how. Is there a simple way to do this using thrust?

```
struct is_odd
{
  __device__
  bool operator()(int &x)
  {
    return (x % 2) == 1;
  }
};

int A[] = {1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1};
int result[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

thrust::find_map_if(A, A+5, result, is_odd()); // this function doesn't exist!

// result = {0, 2, 3, 5, -1}
```

I need this map to scatter an arbitrary array of data (which is not A).

Comment: Is there a `find_map_if` primitive in Thrust? Also, in your example, `is_odd()` will operate on `A`, not on the corresponding element indices. So, I do not understand why is `result = {0, 2, 3, 5, -1}`?

Comment: no, the primitive doesn't exist. that is what the comment "this function doesn't exist" is supposed to indicate. I am trying to demonstrate what I *want* the code to do, and I completely understand that this will not compile. Think of it as pseudocode. Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: also, while I realise the general attitude of being downvoted on stackoverflow seems to just be "suck it up and deal with it", could you please tell me (whoever voted down my question) what I was downvoted for so that I can improve my question? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways to tackle this.  Here's one possible approach:

1. Create an index array (or use a counting iterator)

   ```
   int  A[] = {1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1};
   int iA[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   ```

   you can use `thrust::sequence` to do this, for example.  Or you can skip the explicit generation of `iA` and  use a counting_iterator in the next step.
2. Use [thrust::remove_copy_if](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__stream__compaction.html#ga5ca0dab8bdfb53742f0fca18156c8987) to take the index array and reduce it to the elements that correspond to the result of your test.

Here's a fully worked example.  Note that remove_copy_if copies elements for which the functor test is *false*:

```
$ cat t596.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#define DSIZE 6

struct is_odd
{
  __device__
  bool operator()(int x) const
  {
    return !(x&1);
  }
};

int main(){

  int A[] = {1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1};
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_A(A, A+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> result(DSIZE, -1);
  thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
  thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first+DSIZE;
  thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator r_end = thrust::remove_copy_if(first, last, d_A.begin(), result.begin(), is_odd());
  thrust::copy(result.begin(), r_end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t596 t596.cu
$ ./t596
0 2 3 5
0 2 3 5 -1 -1
$
```